# Object properties are sorted alphabetically in online code editors

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, properties, alphabetical

```
let menu = {
  width: 200,
  height: 300,
  title: "My menu"
};

let myF = obj => { for(let prop in obj){
if(typeof obj[prop] == "number" ){
obj[prop] *= 2}

}  

}

myF(menu);
console.log(menu);
```

I have created a function that multiplies all numeric properties. While I was working in online code editor jsfiddle, the properties of menu object were surprisingly sorted alphabetically:

```
{
  height: 600,
  title: "My menu",
  width: 400
}
```

I just wonder why online code editors behave like that. Also, in my opinion, this feature can easily misdirect while working with massive code lines, so is it a bad habit to code in such places?

Comment: Are you saying that they were reordered in the source code? You probably pressed the "Format code" button, and the chosen formatter has a setting to sort simple objects alphabetically.

Comment: No, it doesn't affect the source code. When I run console.log(menu) to see output at the end, it just reorders properties of the object in the console of jsfiddle and codepen. I do not interact any of these format buttons. @Bergi

Comment: Ah ok. Well, objects are not an ordered data structure, it shouldn't matter in what order they are printed. Use a `Map` instead if you want to rely on iteration order.

Answer (score 0):

A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order.Your code is not affected by the order.

Comment: "*A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order*"—As of ES2020, that is [not true anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties).

Comment: But, when I run this code in browser's console, object properties are sorted in original order.

Comment: @ÖzgürCoşkuner it depends which version of ES, fiddle uses and which one being used by your browser.

Comment: @str The order might be deterministic now for consistency between engines, but that doesn't mean that objects are supposed to be used as an ordered structure now.

Comment: @Bergi I agree, I was not meaning to imply that.